jakarta.mail.util.StreamProvider: org.eclipse.angus.mail.util.MailStreamProvider not a subtype after migrating to jakarta.mail
So I am in the progress of migrating a Java 1.8 Spring 3 SpringMVC application with Spring Security running on Tomcat 9 to Spring 6 with Spring Security 6 running Java 17 on Tomcat 11, and I am not using Spring Boot. So far I was able to migrate everything Tomcat 9 Spring 5, Security 5, and Java 11. Once I took the step for Java 17, Spring 6, Security 6 and Tomcat 11. I ran into issues migrating javax.mail to jakarta.mail. I ran into this Spring-boot-starter-mail 3.1.1 throws "Not provider of jakarta.mail.util.StreamProvider was found" but was able to resolve it from the solution, but I now ran into a new error where I get the following: "jakarta.mail.util.StreamProvider: org.eclipse.angus.mail.util.MailStreamProvider not a subtype"
context.xml
<Context>
   <Resource auth="Container" mail.debug="true" mail.from="email"
       mail.smtp.host="email" mail.smtp.port="25" mail.user="user"
       name="mail/Session" type="jakarta.mail.Session" />
</Context>

pom.xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>qaqc</artifactId>
<version>2.3.3</version>
<parent>
    <artifactId>quickbuild-reports</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.10</version>
</parent>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<properties>
    <spring.version>6.2.0</spring.version>
    <spring.security.version>6.4.1</spring.security.version>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>17</source>
                <target>17</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.01</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.22.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.castor</groupId>
        <artifactId>castor</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-js</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-binding</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.1.Final</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test-mvc</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.M1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20240303</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
        <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.157</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.5.2.Final</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jmx</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ESAPI</groupId>
        <artifactId>ESAPI</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.4</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/ESAPI-1.4.4.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <!--
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.owasp.esapi</groupId>
      <artifactId>esapi</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jmimemagic</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmimemagic</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.4</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId>
        <artifactId>Saxon-HE</artifactId>
        <version>9.4</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>3.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery-maskedinput</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>font-awesome</artifactId>
        <version>4.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootbox</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
    </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>datatables</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
        <artifactId>datatables-buttons</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
        <artifactId>datatables.net-buttons</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.7</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap3-typeahead</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap-toggle</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>Eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker</artifactId>
        <version>4.17.47</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap-multiselect</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.13-1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap-select</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.4</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>es6-promise</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfmake</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.31</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jszip</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>momentjs</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
        <artifactId>material-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.24</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-ses</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.32</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>rome</groupId>
        <artifactId>rome</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.mail-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.transaction-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
        <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.angus</groupId>
        <artifactId>angus-mail</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.angus</groupId>
        <artifactId>angus-activation</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

applicationContext.xml
<bean id="javaMailSession" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/mail/Session"/>
</bean>

<bean id="javaMailSenderImpl" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="session" ref="javaMailSession"/>
</bean>

stacktrace
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: jakarta.mail.util.StreamProvider: org.eclipse.angus.mail.util.MailStreamProvider not a subtype
at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:593) ~[?:?]
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1244) ~[?:?]
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1273) ~[?:?]
at java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1309) ~[?:?]
at java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1393) ~[?:?]
at jakarta.mail.util.FactoryFinder.factoryFromServiceLoader(FactoryFinder.java:161) ~[jakarta.mail-api-2.1.3.jar:?]
at jakarta.mail.util.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:75) ~[jakarta.mail-api-2.1.3.jar:?]
at jakarta.mail.util.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:40) ~[jakarta.mail-api-2.1.3.jar:?]
at jakarta.mail.util.StreamProvider.provider(StreamProvider.java:199) ~[jakarta.mail-api-2.1.3.jar:?]
at jakarta.mail.Session.<init>(Session.java:257) ~[jakarta.mail-api-2.1.3.jar:?]
at jakarta.mail.Session.getInstance(Session.java:310) ~[jakarta.mail-api-2.1.3.jar:?]
at org.apache.naming.factory.MailSessionFactory.getObjectInstance(MailSessionFactory.java:125) ~[catalina.jar:11.0.1]
at org.apache.naming.factory.FactoryBase.getObjectInstance(FactoryBase.java:88) ~[catalina.jar:11.0.1]
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:342) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:544) ~[catalina.jar:11.0.1]
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:148) ~[catalina.jar:11.0.1]
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:530) ~[catalina.jar:11.0.1]
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:148) ~[catalina.jar:11.0.1]
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:530) ~[catalina.jar:11.0.1]
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:148) ~[catalina.jar:11.0.1]
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:530) ~[catalina.jar:11.0.1]
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:155) ~[catalina.jar:11.0.1]
at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:144) ~[catalina.jar:11.0.1]
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:409) ~[?:?]
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lambda$lookup$0(JndiTemplate.java:157) ~[spring-context-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:92) ~[spring-context-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:157) ~[spring-context-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:179) ~[spring-context-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:96) ~[spring-context-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:114) ~[spring-context-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:239) ~[spring-context-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:225) ~[spring-context-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1849) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1798) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
... 53 more

